# How to detect if a string contains a regex pattern using dplyr pipe mutate

Tags: r, regex, dplyr

I have the following data frame:

```r
library(tidyverse)

dat <- structure(list(peptide_id = c("PD_22374", "PD_20472", "PD_17483"
), peptide = c("EVHNPWNFIPDFQRSRQQHAFKKIRKHRRA", "KKEPQICTWKIQVRFSMNKKVWRKGTQKKK", 
"NESVPKTHGDVINTGIKERRSKKAKSITKV")), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))


dat
#> # A tibble: 3 x 2
#>   peptide_id peptide                       
#>   <chr>      <chr>                         
#> 1 PD_22374   EVHNPWNFIPDFQRSRQQHAFKKIRKHRRA
#> 2 PD_20472   KKEPQICTWKIQVRFSMNKKVWRKGTQKKK
#> 3 PD_17483   NESVPKTHGDVINTGIKERRSKKAKSITKV
```

I'd like to detect which of the rows above contain this regex pattern `K[KR].{1}[KR]`.

We'd like to have another column which gives a YES or NO. 
How can I go about it?

This figure showed which rows contain that pattern:

[image]

Comment: Like this? `mutate(dat, yes_no = str_detect(peptide, "K[KR].{1}[KR]"))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)
```

You can use `str_detect()` from the `stringr` package (also part of the tidyverse) to detect if the pattern is there and use `ifelse()` to translate `TRUE` and `FALSE` to `'YES'` and `'NO'`:

```
dat %>% 
  mutate(ind = ifelse(str_detect(peptide, "K[KR].{1}[KR]"), "YES", "NO"))
```

The result is:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  peptide_id peptide                        ind  
  <chr>      <chr>                          <chr>
1 PD_22374   EVHNPWNFIPDFQRSRQQHAFKKIRKHRRA YES  
2 PD_20472   KKEPQICTWKIQVRFSMNKKVWRKGTQKKK NO   
3 PD_17483   NESVPKTHGDVINTGIKERRSKKAKSITKV YES
```

Comment: To stay within `tidyverse` maybe use `if_else`?

Comment: I agree, if you wanted to be 100% `tidyverse`, you would go for `if_else()`. But I don't think it has an advantage over `ifelse()` here, so I went for (the in this case faster) `base` solution.

Answer (score 5):

```
dat%>%
  mutate(ind= grepl("K[KR].{1}[KR]",peptide))

# A tibble: 3 x 3
  peptide_id peptide                        ind  
  <chr>      <chr>                          <lgl>
1 PD_22374   EVHNPWNFIPDFQRSRQQHAFKKIRKHRRA TRUE 
2 PD_20472   KKEPQICTWKIQVRFSMNKKVWRKGTQKKK FALSE
3 PD_17483   NESVPKTHGDVINTGIKERRSKKAKSITKV TRUE
```